# Is there a way to get Editor type from Input Method Engine (IME)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently working on a keyboard project and have noticed that some functionalities, such as setComposingRegion() of IME, differ in Jetpack Compose's TextField compared to traditional EditText. Is there a way to determine whether an Editor is a Compose TextField or an EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't.  And those aren't the only two options either.  The entire idea behind the InputConnection is that you don't need to know the details of what's on the other side.  It could be one of those.  It could be a WebView's text field.  It could be a custom text field written from scratch (for say a text editor or word processor).  It could even be something completely out there-  like a game where it's using the keyboard for input but not displaying the typed characters.  You don't know what it is and shouldn't care.  And yes, they will all send slightly different timings and orders of calls to the InputConnection to accomplish the same thing.  Compose text fields are actually going to be the least of your worries in the long term.